# @value( ${} ) в spring не работает

Tags: java, xml, spring

Пишу приложение на java с использованием Spring. Нужно передать значение ключа из файла app.properties в поле класса. Передает null. Выскакивает NullPointerException, уже не знаю что и делать, помогите кто чем может

конфигурация spring:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/app.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:app.properties"/>
</bean>
```

файл properties:

```
price=^[1-9][0-9.]{0,10}
```

в классе:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
....
@Value("${price}")
private String price;
private Pattern PRICE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(price);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Value("${price}")` в твоём случае работает. Другое дело, что ты вызываешь `private Pattern PRICE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(price);` до того, как отработает `@Value`. Тебе надо перенести логику инициализации `PRICE_REGEX` в **post**-конструктор. На выходе должно получиться примерно так:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Component
public class Question909652 implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${price}")
    private String price;
    private Pattern PRICE_REGEX;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        PRICE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(price);
    }
}
```

Ну или можно похитрить и использовать всю мощь [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Component
public class Question909652 {

    @Value("#{T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile('${price}')}")
    private Pattern PRICE_REGEX;

}
```

P.S. Как правильно заметил @Qwertiy, у тебя очень странное регулярное выражение для цены, быть может тебе больше подойдёт `[0-9]*([.][0-9]{1,2})?`

Comment: А ещё сам паттерн неправильный)

Comment: Спасибо, работает)))

Answer (score 0):

Добавь аннотацию `@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")`.

Comment: к сожалению, та же ошибка(